# nacl_io bind fails with EPERM

Tags: google-nativeclient

I wrote some demo app, that uses nacl_io sockets,
but bind fails with errno == EPERM

building with pepper_37,
Google Chrome 39.0.2171.95 (m) 
OS Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2 SP1 64 bit
PNaCl translator version 0.1.0.13769

chrome flags:
--allow-nacl-socket-api=localhost --no-sandbox --enable-nacl

```
class ProxyTesterInstance : public pp::Instance 
   {
     public:

  explicit ProxyTesterInstance(PP_Instance instance, PPB_GetInterface get_interface) : pp::Instance(instance)
  {
    nacl_io_init_ppapi(instance, get_interface);
  }
  virtual ~ProxyTesterInstance() {}

  virtual void HandleMessage(const pp::Var& var_message) 
  {
    if (!var_message.is_string())
        return;

    std::string message = var_message.AsString();

    if (message == kStartString) 
    {
        reply(kReplyStartString);

        int fd = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
        myaddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
        myaddr.sin_port = htons(50000);
        inet_aton("0.0.0.0", &myaddr.sin_addr );
        int res = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)); //returns -1

        myaddr.sin_port = htons(80);
        inet_aton("173.194.113.2", &myaddr.sin_addr );

        res = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)); //returns 0

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nacl_io` assumes that it is being run on a worker thread, not the main thread. This is because many socket functions are blocking, but it is illegal to block the main thread in a NaCl application. Unfortunately, the error messages are not very clear explaining this constraint.

The easiest way to make this code work is to use the ppapi_simple library. It will initialize nacl_io for you and start running your code on a worker thread. At this point, you'll be able to make blocking calls (such as bind). It also gives you a main-like entry point instead of having to create a `pp::Instance`.

Take a look at some of the demos in the NaCl SDK (e.g. `examples/demo/earth`, `examples/demo/pi_generator`) for how to use ppapi_simple.

Comment: Changed to use ppapi_simple, previous code (the socket stuff) is first thing i do in main. Socket created, but bind fails with EACCES. i start chrome with --allow-nacl-socket-api=localhost also tried to add --no-sandbox flags, but it didn't help. (Nacl socket api in settings disabled).

Comment: This is the error given when the page accessing sockets doesn't have permission. Make sure that your app is being served from http://localhost/... otherwise you need to change the line to --allow-nacl-socket-api=<my origin>